# Specific tests from a Suite Category

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-suite, suite

Is it possible to run only some methods (not all) from a test case in Junit4 (Eclipse)? 
I have 2 test cases and I want to implement a test suite which contains all the methods from one test case (I did that by adding the @Category annotation to all the tests from the first test case and then in the suite i used @IncludeCategory) and some methods from the second one.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not directly related, but this is a way to [compute 'Tests by Category' counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778167/10524205).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just put the `@Category` annotation containing the same marker:

- on **class** level - on a class from which all methods should be included in a suite.
- on **method** level - annotate selected methods within a class when not all of them should be included in a suite.

...and include that category within your suite.

I believe that first `SlowTestSuite` class from an example [in Category documentation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories) shows the situation you've asked about - it runs all tests from `B` and only some from `A`.